# Which is quicker: Select of existing row vs Update where no row exists?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Which would run the fastest?

1. Select from a table using the primary key (integer, clustered index, 1,000,000+ rows)
2. Attempt an update on a different table, where the row does not exist? (where clause on integer primary key, clustered index, 200,000+ rows)

### Background

We currently have some procedures that need to maintain a filtered copy of their table.

Tables involved:

- `[MasterTable]` that contains the filter criteria
- `[ChildTable]` to be filtered
- `[ChildFilterTable]` to hold the filtered records

This is currently being done by:

1. Select filter criteria
2. If filter criteria match then:

   1. Attempt an update
   2. If no records updated, insert a new record

Example SQL:

```
DECLARE @FilterValue INT

/* Get FilterValue to check */
SELECT @FilterValue = FilterValue FROM [MasterTable] WHERE ID = @IDFromChildTable

IF @FilterValue = 123
BEGIN
    /* Attempt update */
    UPDATE [ChildFilterTable] SET
        ...
    WHERE ChildID = @IDFromChildTable

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        /* Row not there yet, insert it! */
        INSERT INTO [ChildFilterTable] (ChildID, ....) VALUES (@IDFromChildTable, ....)
    END
END
```

### Proposed change

Change to:

1. Attempt an update
2. If no records updated, then:

   1. Select filter criteria
   2. If filter criteria match then: insert a new record

So:

```
DECLARE @FilterValue INT

/* Attempt update */
UPDATE [ChildFilterTable] SET
    ...
WHERE ChildID = @IDFromChildTable

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    /* Get FilterValue to check */
    SELECT @FilterValue = FilterValue FROM [MasterTable] WHERE ID = @IDFromChildTable

    IF @FilterValue = 123
    BEGIN
        /* Row not there yet, insert it! */
        INSERT INTO [ChildFilterTable] (ChildID, ....) VALUES (@IDFromChildTable, ....)
    END
END
```

***Note:** Business rules confirm that the filter value will never change once setup on the `[MasterTable]` so we don't need to worry about updating a value which does not match the filter record (ie: if it's in the ChildFilterTable, we want to update it.*

Comment: Your proposed change sounds a lot better to me than your existing code. I've actually resolved three separate deadlock issues just by changing similar code in the same way - from a select to see if it should update or insert, to an update and then an insert if no rows were affected. As for @gbn's answer, perhaps you could have two versions of the proc that are called depending on the underlying version of SQL Server, because `MERGE` is absolutely the best way to handle this IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you not use the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement added with SQL Server 2008 to "UPSERT" in one atomic operation?

```
DECLARE @FilterValue INT

;MERGE 
INTO ChildFilterTable AS CFT
USING  (your filter, source thing here)
                  ON (CFT.ChildID = ...)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN update stuff
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN insert stuff;
```

Comment: Unfortunately we're on a mixture of 2005 and 2008 at the moment and need to maintain backward compatibility.  Q: Do you know if under the hood the merge operates faster than an update if rowcount = 0 insert?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's quicker. It is one operation, not 2. But I haven't benchmarked it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check how expensive your INSERTs/UPDATEs are?

If you care about performance, I would always call the INSERT or UPDATE first, depending on what is more likely to be necessary in your scenario. So if you expect your data to be in 80% of the cases already there, call the UPDATE first, then on fail the INSERT. If the record will usually have to be inserted most of the cases, call the INSERT first.

Comment: In our tests we have found that the update is *generally* more likely and so we by default try the update first...  there are some `[ChildTables]` where that is not the case, but performance wise we've found the update call where no rows match is quicker than an if exists call.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is [set statistics time on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) at the start of both the queries, and review the results. Remember that if the query is getting cached, you will see different results, so you may have to clear the cache while testing to see how they work out.